# Login PHP me da fallo en el session_start()

Tags: php, login

Estoy haciendo un login con **Bootstrap y PHP**. Y no sé porqué la clase que tiene que validar mi usuario me da fallo en el `session_start()`. Necesito el `_SESSION_` para devolver mensajes al login en caso de error.

**Clase que me valida:**

```
<?php
require "./bbdd/usuarios.php";
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

    if(comprobarUsuario($user)){
        if(comprobarEstado($user)){
            if(comprobarDatos($user, $pass)){
                            $session_start();
                            $_SESSION['usuario'] = $recuperarUsuario($user, $pass);
                            header("location: ../B_Principal_Perfil.php");
            }
            else{
                            $session_start();
                            $_SESSION['alerta'] = "La contraseña no es correcta";
                            header("location: ../Login.php");
            }
        }
        else{
                    $session_start();
                    $_SESSION['alerta'] =  "La cuenta de este usuario ha sido eliminada";
                    header("location: ../Login.php");
        }
    }
    else {
            $session_start();
            $_SESSION['alerta'] =  "Ese user no está registrado";
            header("location: ../Login.php");
    }




    function comprobarUsuario($usuario){
        $comprobar = false;
        $sql = "SELECT usuario FROM 'db_promodisenios_users' WHERE usuario='" . $usuario . "';";
        $conect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_promodisenios","root", "", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
                $resultado = $conect->query($sql);      
                 if (isset($resultado) && $resultado != null) {
                    $row = $resultado->fetch();
                    if($row['usuario'] == $usuario ){
                        $comprobar = true;
                    }

                 }
        return $comprobar;
    }
    function comprobarEstado($usuario){
        $comprobar = false;
        $sql = "SELECT usuario FROM 'db_promodisenios_users' WHERE usuario='" 
                . $usuario . "' AND estado=1;";
        $conect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_promodisenios","root", "", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
                $resultado = $conect->query($sql);      
                 if (isset($resultado)) {
                    $row = $resultado->fetch();
                    if($row['usuario'] == $usuario ){
                        $comprobar = true;
                    }

                 }
        return $comprobar;
    }
    function comprobarDatos($usuario, $password){
        $comprobar = false;
        $sql = "SELECT usuario FROM `db_promodisenios_users`" 
                ."WHERE usuario='". $usuario ."'AND contrasenia='". $password ."'";
        $conect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_promodisenios","root", "", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
                $resultado = $conect->query($sql);      
                 if (isset($resultado)) {
                    $row = $resultado->fetch();
                    if($row['usuario'] == $usuario ){
                        $comprobar = true;
                    }

                 }
        return $comprobar;
    }
    function recuperarUsuario($usuario, $password) {
        $sql = "SELECT id_user, usuario, nombre, apellido1, apellido2, biografia FROM `db_promodisenios_users`" 
                ."WHERE usuario='". $usuario ."'AND contrasenia='". $password ."'";
        $conect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_promodisenios","root", "", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
                $resultado = $conect->query($sql);      
                 if (isset($resultado)) {
                    $row = $resultado->fetch();
                    $usuario = New usuarios($row);

                 }
        return $usuario; 
    }

?>
```

**Login:**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>  
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!-- Bootstrap y jquery para desplegables--> 
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <link href="css/B_Principal.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Login</title>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="login-overlay" class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">PromoDiseños</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <div class="well">
                                <form id="loginForm" method="POST" action="./include/f_login.php" novalidate="novalidate">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="username" class="control-label">Usuario</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" required="" title="Introduzca usuario con el que se registr�">
                                        <span class="help-block"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="password" class="control-label">Contraseña</label>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" required="" title="Introduzca su contrase�a">
                                        <span class="help-block"></span> 
                                    </div>
                                    <?php
                                    if (isset($_SESSION['alerta'])) {
                                        echo "<div id='loginErrorMsg' class='alert alert-error hide'>" . $_SESSION['alerta'] . "</div>";
                                        unset($_SESSION['alerta']);
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Login</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p class="lead">Registrese ahora <span class="text-success">GRATIS</span></p>
                            <ul class="list-unstyled" style="line-height: 2">
                                <li><span class="fa fa-check text-success"></span> Cree su perfil gratuitamente </li>
                                <li><span class="fa fa-check text-success"></span> Promocione su trabajo gratis </li>
                                <li><span class="fa fa-check text-success"></span> Consiga seguidores en suss redes </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- CAMBIAR LINK CUANDO TENGA EL FORMULARIO DE REGISTRO-->
                            <p><a href="/new-customer/" class="btn btn-info btn-block">�Registrarmme ahora!</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Mensaje de Error:**

```
Notice: Undefined variable: session_start in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject2\include\f_login.php on line 26
```

Comment: Que mensaje de error obtienes?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: session_start in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject2\include\f_login.php on line 26

Comment: El problema es que en tu clase para validar estas llamando session_start() como variable `$session_start();` quita el signo dolar y llamala como funcion

Comment: Si, eso lo sabia pero estaba probando porque me lo recomendó netbeans. Pero ese no es el fallo.... :-/

Comment: Cual es la linea 26 que menciona el error?

Comment: Entonces pon el fallo con session_start() porque ahí el error que pusiste te lo marca por eso

Comment: El error es como lo menciona JuanPinzón  y Sergio  en su respuesta , además podrías iniciar la sesión antes de iniciar las comparaciones. (inicio del archivo)

Answer (score 3):

Tu error está en `$session_start();`

Es un método no una variable, se pone sin el "$" `session_start();`

Comment: Si, eso lo sabia pero estaba probando porque me lo recomendó netbeans. Pero ese no es el fallo.... :-/

Answer (score 2):

Quita todos los $session_start();.
Como ya te dijeron no tiene que ser una variable y agregalo al inicio del archivo,
o por si utilizas otro metodo que utilice session_start(), agrega esto al principio:

```
if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
    session_start();
}
```

y no necesitas en cada comparacion llamar a session_start() por si pasa algo o no,llamalo al principio y listo.
Suerte con eso,saludos.